# Difference between string.ToLower and TextInfo.ToLower

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between the two? And when should I use each of them?

Comment: Or just see [this website](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textinfo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none.

`string.ToLower` calls `TextInfo.ToLower` behind the scenes.

From String.cs:

```
    // Creates a copy of this string in lower case. 
    public String ToLower() {
        return this.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
    }

    // Creates a copy of this string in lower case.  The culture is set by culture.
    public String ToLower(CultureInfo culture) { 
        if (culture==null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("culture"); 
        } 
        return culture.TextInfo.ToLower(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> The **ToLower** and ToLowerInvariant methods on strings **actually call into the TextInfo virtual property when invoked**. For this reason, they always carry the overhead of this virtual property access. The string type methods have no difference in result values but are slower in some cases.

[**The full article + Benchmark**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textinfo)

For the sake of simplicity use `str.ToLower()` and forget about the issue!